# Advisory Lock from the nodejs mysql and mysql2 driver returns null

Tags: mysql, node.js

When attempting to obtain an advisory lock:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

I'm receiving a `null` response instead of the `0` or `1` as specified by the MySQL documentation and as seen when I issue the query through the MySQL client.

[image]

```
import test from 'ava'

import mysql from 'mysql1'

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  port: 3306,
  database: 'test',
  password: '',
})

const foo = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(1)
})

const multiQuery = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const sql = `
    SELECT GET_LOCK('test2', -1) AS test3;
  `
  pool.query(sql, (err, res) => (err == null ? resolve(res) : reject(err)))
})

test(async (t) => {
  const response = await multiQuery()
  console.log(response)
  t.is(await foo(), 1)
})
```

Response:
[image: Database Driver Response]

Is this expected?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between MySql and MariaDB in their GET_LOCK implementations.

From the [MySql GET_LOCK() Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock):

> Tries to obtain a lock with a name given by the string str, using a timeout of timeout seconds. **A negative timeout value means infinite timeout**. The lock is exclusive. While held by one session, other sessions cannot obtain a lock of the same name.

From the [MariaDB GET_LOCK() Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/get_lock/):

> Tries to obtain a lock with a name given by the string str, using a timeout of timeout seconds. Returns 1 if the lock was obtained successfully, 0 if the attempt timed out (for example, because another client has previously locked the name), or NULL if an error occurred (such as running out of memory or the thread was killed with mysqladmin kill).

Both implementations return NULL if an error occurred, however, the MariaDB does not support the **negative timeout**.  Therefore, MariaDB will return NULL when passed a negative integer as the timeout parameter to the GET_LOCK() function.

Give my query of:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('test2', -1) AS test3
```

MariaDB will respond with NULL and MySQL will respond with 1